# Position for three divs

Tags: html, css

How could I align three divs as below?

[image]

And more, I would like div2, div3 to be fixed when I scroll. I tried with `position: fixed`, but I need to hardcode how many pixels needs from left and top to div2/div3 and this is not good because when I change the resolution of the screen div2/div3 do not appear on the page.

Comment: *I need to hardcode how many pixels* You can use percentages and/or media queries in order to adapt the result to the display.

Comment: Since it appears you've tried some things, how about sharing those attempts with us, so that we don't suggest something you've already tried? Also, it will help to have some HTML/CSS to use for examples, rather than a picture.

Comment: make use of percentages (sizes in % instead px) to get rid of problems with zoom in and out.

Comment: @A.L if I use percentages for left then div2/div3 will be over div1

Comment: You could try out the new [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) if you're feeling a bit bold and don't like IE: https://jsfiddle.net/nrmogx16/.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="fixed-wrapper">
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.one{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fixed-wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.two{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.three{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something more like this. It's fully responsive. The vh can be replaced with pixels or percentages as need be, or let the content size the containers.

```css
#one, #two, #three{
 border: 0.5em solid black;
 width: calc(47% - 1em);
}
#one{
 height: 200vh;
 margin: 2% 1% 2% 2%;
 float:left;
}
#right_column{
 position:fixed;
 left: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 2% 0 0 0;
}
#two, #three{
 height: 40vh;
}
#two{
 margin: 0 2% 1% 1%;
}
#three{
 margin: 1% 2% 2% 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="right_column">
 <div id="two">&nbsp;</div>
 <div id="three">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```